# Documentation when Package Name = Main Function Name

Tags: r

I am writing an R package names `slidify`. The main function in the package is also named `slidify`. When I run `devtools::check`, I get a warning that there is a conflict in the Rd files.

I don't want to rename the function, since it succintly conveys what the package is intended for. What is best practice in this situation? Should typing `? slidify` lead to the function documentation or package documentation?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd make a "slidify-package.Rd" file, (or a "slidify-package.R" file with nothing but roxygen comment blocks)

`?slidify` should lead to the function documentation and `slidify?package` should lead to the package documentation, and both help pages should have a link to the other (in the seealso section, for example)

Comment: Thanks. I already had `package.R` file with Roxygen style documentation. The problem was I had an `@alias slidify` directive, which was causing problems. I removed it and now have `@seealso` directives in both places. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I think you mean `package?slidify`

Comment: @hadley, heh. Thanks. I wasn't aware of that syntax.

Comment: @hadley - I wasn't aware of that syntax either! Thank you very much.  I usually use something like `?"stats-package"`.  Although I tend to forget the quotes initially (`?stats-package`) and end up at the help for Arithmetic Operators...